# Weird tab close icon behavior on chrome or new feature?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-tabs

I just noticed that as soon as I close a single tab on Chrome (version 23.0.1271.64 m), all the other tabs display the X icon as if trying to help to close a lot of them without switching to them. Problem is the X does not go away after an amount or time or anything. All my tabs ow have that X button on each tab, which makes it easy to close a tab by mistake and is just plain annoying.

I had actually become used to the way Chrome handles tab closing, which was only showing the close button if the tab was active.

Not really sure if this is a new feature or a weird bug due to an extension of mine, but if anyone can confirm its a new feature, is there a way to disable it? Has someone had this problem before?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Just checked and all tabs display the "X" button by default for me, same version of Chrome. I cannot say whether this is a new feature of not since I normally do not use Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same version of Chrome, and what I observe is this: if I have few tabs open, all X buttons are visible. If I open many tabs, then the X buttons on inactive tabs go away. I think that when "all the other tabs display[ed] the X icon as if trying to help to close a lot of them", what really happened is that Chrome decided there were now few enough tabs to show the X buttons for all.

I was under the impression that Chrome always behaved this way, although they may have tweaked exactly when the X "hiding" happens. For example, see this screenshot from 2008:

[image: Chrome Screenshot]

Both tabs do have X buttons. Here's another screenshot, from 2010, with more tabs, and still X buttons:

[image]

Finally, here's a screenshot with really squished tabs, and no X buttons:

[image]

(Not sure what the date on this photo is, but from the look of the Chrome browser, it's not recent).

Comment: you are so right. i'm used to having 30+ tabs open at any given time, that i never noticed that if there are too many, the x's show up all the time. i just did the test and opened 30+, and they go away. thanks for that. hopefully google would allow us to set a flag for this..